# How to find all points inside circle sector of 2 concentric circles in an optimized way

Tags: circles, image-processing

I have 2 concentric circles with known radiuses and sector start and end points of each circle($A, B, C, D$ and $O$ in figure is known) . I detected the circles from image. I have 2 points on the inside circle and 2 points on the outside circle. I want to find all points between these 4 points inside circular ring.

If we draw a tangent to the midpoint of given 2 points(A and B) in the outer circle and form a line then find 2 points meet the lines OB and OA.
If we join inner circle points we get a line. Then we have to check each point inside this trapezoid and check whether the point is inside the sector. But I don't know how to do it mathematically in an optimized way.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image: I have to find points marked in red and all points inside the trapezoid]

Comment: Are you asking about the area of the grey shading?

Comment: Not sure what you mean as there are an infinite number of such points. If you want to check a point is inside, convert it to polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$, then check that r is between your two radii values and $\theta$ is an angle between 0 and 30 degrees.

Comment: Yes,gray shading

Comment: Look up the area of a sector. Subtract the smaller sector area from the larger.

Comment: I detected the circles from 2k*2k image. So there may not be infinite number of points.I need to find all points inside the gray shading

Comment: Thank you so much.But I need to find it in an optimized way. I have to loop only through these 4 points A,B,C and D.

Comment: Convert A, C and D to polar form. Test if a point in polar form has radius between the radii of A and C and angle between the angles of C and D.

Comment: How to find the red points marked in figure

Comment: Bisect AB and you have a right angled triangle with base 7cm and angle at O of 15 degrees. You can now find other lengths in that triangle. Finding the location of those points needs a coordinate system first though.